# In React-Router-Dom, my link is changing the url but it is not rendering matched components or passing any props to this.props.child

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

## This is inside ReactDOM.render[index.js]

```
  <Router history={hasHistory}>
  <Route component={App}>
        <IndexRoute path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/Blog" component={Blog} />
        <Route path="/Trust" component={Safety} />
  </Route>
```

#The bellow code is in App.js

```
  <div>
    <div>
    {this.props.children || <Home/>}
    </div>
    <Footer/>
  </div>
```

## The above code is in Footer.js[Link used]

```
  <Row>
<Col md={8} id="footernav">
 <ul>
<li><Link to="/">Home </Link></li>
<li><Link to="/about">About </Link></li>
<li><Link to="/Blog">Blog</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/Terms">Terms & Condition</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/Trust">Trust & Safety</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/Help">Help</Link></li>
 </ul>
 </Col>
 </Row>
```

## This above code is inside footer.js

Comment: Could you add your `App` component code to your question?

Comment: We need as much code as you can provide, but taking a quick sight, you should not have that `div` inside surrounding your rutes. But share App's code please

Comment: Hi, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve about how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, so we can best help you.

Comment: hi, here is the app.js

Comment: @FabianSchultz 

Here is the App.js and Footer.js File

Comment: @Facundo La Rocca
Here is the App.js and Footer.js File

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Router is not implemented correctly. You can modify it like so:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

I've shortened it for brevity. Notice three main differences:

1. The first route path has the default path, which is "/"
2. The IndexRoute refers to the parent Route path, so it doesn't have a path at all
3. Nested Routes do not have "/" inside their path, since they're mounted on top of the main Route.

Let me know how it goes ;)

Comment: Hi, @Luca Argenziano, Thanks for your suggestion but 
In my case the above, code doesn't work. 
I am still facing the trouble, please help, it's been 3 days, unable to get solution.

Comment: Can you do a fiddle/plunker of your code? Or linking to the repo? Because there could be a lot of things that are breaking your app (the first I've noticed, ```hasHistory``` doesn't exist, ```hashHistory``` do exist instead). If you can provide a better overview of your app I could debug deeper. @A.Mayank

Comment: Hi @Luca
https://bitbucket.org/pmagar4u/anmole/src/4ea2fd62ac02?at=master